# subset-friendly version of match()

Tags: r, match, subset

I dislike (or don't understand) the `match()` function because it outputs `NA` if it doesn't find a value and because it returns only the first occurrence of a match. Both is bad for subsetting one dataframe by another, at least in my situation.

Let the data be

```
df1 <- data.frame(id=c(1:3,3:4), val= 11:15)
df2 <- data.frame(id= c(2,0,3,1), val=91:94)
```

I want to subset `df1` by the id's of `df2`. So my desired output is

```
df_expected <- data.frame(id= c(2,3,3,1), val= c(12,13,14,11))
```

But if I try to subset `df1` using `df1[match(df2$id, df1$id), ]` I get not what I expect, firstly because `match` returns a `NA` since it can't find id `0` in `df1` which adds a row containing just `NA`s and secondly because it returns just the first occurrence of id `3` in `df1` but I want to have all occurrences of a match.

How to adjust the match function so that it does as described above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of `%in%` and `which`. The output is not in the order you posted, though.

```r
df1 <- data.frame(id=c(1:3,3:4), val= 11:15)
df2 <- data.frame(id= c(2,0,3,1), val=91:94)

i <- which(df1$id %in% df2$id)
df1[i, ]
#>   id val
#> 1  1  11
#> 2  2  12
#> 3  3  13
#> 4  3  14
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Edit

The following will give the posted order.

```r
df1 <- data.frame(id=c(1:3,3:4), val= 11:15)
df2 <- data.frame(id= c(2,0,3,1), val=91:94)

i <- df1$id[df1$id %in% df2$id]
j <- df2$id[df2$id %in% df1$id]
df1[order(match(i, j)), ]
#>   id val
#> 2  2  12
#> 3  3  13
#> 4  3  14
#> 1  1  11
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Edit 2

After reading [Ingo Pingo's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76081359/subset-friendly-version-of-match/76081426?noredirect=1#comment134177543_76081426) and [TarJae's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76081359/subset-friendly-version-of-match/76081426?noredirect=1#comment134177553_76081426) comments I have changed the above solutions to

### 1

```r
i <- which(df1$id %in% df2$id)
df1[order(match(df1$id[i], df2$id)),]
#>   id val
#> 2  2  12
#> 3  3  13
#> 4  3  14
#> 1  1  11
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

### 2

```r
j <- df1$id[df1$id %in% df2$id]
df1[order(match(j, df2$id)), ]
#>   id val
#> 2  2  12
#> 3  3  13
#> 4  3  14
#> 1  1  11
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Interestingly, it also works with simply `j <- df2$id`. Is this a coincidence or is there no need for `j <- df2$id[df2$id %in% df1$id]`?

Comment: If you add `[order(match(df1[i, ]$id, df2$id)), ]` to your first solution it will also work: `i <- which(df1$id %in% df2$id)
df1[i, ][order(match(df1[i, ]$id, df2$id)), ]`.

Answer (score 1):

This will give the expected output:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  filter(id %in% df2$id) %>%
  arrange(match(id, df2$id)) 

  id val
1  2  12
2  3  13
3  3  14
4  1  11
```

or in base R:

```
df_subset <- df1[df1$id %in% df2$id, ]
df_subset[order(match(df_subset$id, df2$id)), ]

  id val
2  2  12
3  3  13
4  3  14
1  1  11
```